# Magento -> Modify Order Confirmation Charset

Tags: magento, character-encoding

I have tried desperately to modify the default charset for order confirmation emails to iso-8859-1. However, it continues to return UTF-8.

The call getCharset calls

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/default_charset');
```

But I don't know where that value is stored.

How would I change the default charset for these emails as I want to include Spanish language in them. All I get is this for the latin chars:

```
�
```

Comment: This value is stored in the file `app/code/core/Mage/Page/etc/config.xml`.

Comment: Modified to <default_charset>iso-8859-1</default_charset> and refreshed cache and still same as shown above.

Comment: My comment only should help you to to locate _"where that value is stored"_. I don't know if it's even used by transactional emails...

Comment: Didn't help fix the problem but thanks, anyway.

Comment: I have decided to use htmlentities to replace the chars vs. changing the charset. I have access to the text in the templates, so changing them, which is what I’m actually doing, is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to overload the `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template::send` method and change the encoding in the 'to' and 'subject' calls as well as pass in the optional encoding parameter in the setBodyHTML/setBodyText call on Zend_Mail object.

Comment: Aha, the Zend Mail object is most likely what is causing the problem, here. Anyway, I solved it by using htmlentities for the accented chars. Thans.